# Including the group name in the apply function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply

Is there away to specify to the `groupby()` call to use the group name in the `apply()` lambda function?

Similar to  if I iterate through groups I can get the group key via the following tuple decomposition:

```
for group_name, subdf in temp_dataframe.groupby(level=0, axis=0):
    print group_name
```

...is there a way to also get the group name in the apply function, such as:

```
temp_dataframe.groupby(level=0,axis=0).apply(lambda group_name, subdf: foo(group_name, subdf)
```

How can I get the group name as an argument for the apply lambda function?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the `name`attribute:

```
temp_dataframe.groupby(level=0,axis=0).apply(lambda x: foo(x.name, x))
```

should work, example:

```
In [132]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('aabccc'), 'b':np.arange(6)})
df

Out[132]:
   a  b
0  a  0
1  a  1
2  b  2
3  c  3
4  c  4
5  c  5

In [134]:
df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: print('name:', x.name, '\nsubdf:',x))

name: a 
subdf:    a  b
0  a  0
1  a  1
name: b 
subdf:    a  b
2  b  2
name: c 
subdf:    a  b
3  c  3
4  c  4
5  c  5
Out[134]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Comment: Good one - how about `transform` though?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D sorry don't understand your question, if you replace `apply` with `transform` then it does the same thing

Comment: Thanks - so `x.name` would work with transform too? I am using transform on a groupby series and i need the key of the groupby to use in a dict - I am doing something as ugly as `df['value'] = df.groupby(['id'])['id'].transform(lambda col: id_to_value_dict[col.unique()[0]])`

Comment: If you want the group names you can call `.groups` and from this get the keys so `df.groupby(['id']).groups.keys()` it's a bit difficult for me to answer without a concrete example and desired result to see

Comment: Just to add to this answer: The 'name' attribute cannot be used as if it were a column - `x['name']` will fail whereas `x.name` works. You can get at the name by using the column attribute (ie. `x[<col>]` which returns the entire `pd.Series`, or `x.iloc[0][<col>]` to get the first element of the Series)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D @EdChum, *no*, with `transform` and `agg`, the function takes a **Series** as input, so the `.name` attribute will be the Series name (i.e column), not the group name. As explained in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55869091)

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong in the case it's a SeriesGroupB its `name` attribute points to the groupby key inside the transform - I used it that way IIRC

Comment: Try `d=pd.DataFrame({'a': ['id1','id2','id3', 'id3'], 'b': [3,6,78,6]}); s=d.groupby('a')['b']; s.transform(lambda x: print(x.name, type(x)))`

Comment: Is this behavior documented anywhere? I don't see it mentioned in the documentation for `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` or `pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy.apply`.

Answer (score 7):

For those who came looking for an answer to the question:

> Including the group name in the **transform** function pandas python

and ended up in this thread, please read on.

Given the following input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': list('aabccc'),
                        'col2': np.arange(6),
                        'col3': np.arange(6)})
```

Data:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   a       0       0
1   a       1       1
2   b       2       2
3   c       3       3
4   c       4       4
5   c       5       5
```

We can access the group name (which is visible from the scope of the calling **apply** function) like this:

```
df.groupby('col1') \
.apply(lambda frame: frame \
       .transform(lambda col: col + 3 if frame.name == 'a' and col.name == 'col2' else col))
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   a       3       0
1   a       4       1
2   b       2       2
3   c       3       3
4   c       4       4
5   c       5       5
```

Note that the call to apply is needed in order to obtain a reference to the sub pandas.core.frame.DataFrame (i.e. frame) which holds the name attribute of the corresponding sub group. The name attribute of the argument of transform (i.e. col) refers to the column/series name.

Alternatively, one could also loop over the groups and then, within each group, over the columns:

```
for grp_name, sub_df in df.groupby('col1'):
    for col in sub_df:
        if grp_name == 'a' and col == 'col2':
            df.loc[df.col1 == grp_name, col] = sub_df[col] + 3
```

My use case is quite rare and this was the only way to achieve my goal (as of pandas v0.24.2). However, I'd recommend exploring the pandas documentation thoroughly because there most likely is an easier vectorised solution to what you may need this construct for.

Comment: super disappointed that the same attribute isn't available in transform as well as.